# how do i correctly use clip-rule="evenodd" so i can cut one shape out of another?

Tags: svg

this is my code:

```
<svg style="position: absolute; z-index: 100;" width="100%" height="100%" 
         viewPort="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="elroyclip">
            <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M54.621,44.397V60.23h15.434v7.456H47.66V44.397H27.99v23.289H5.594V60.23h15.443V44.397H0v-3.819C0,18.198,16.965,0,37.826,0c20.863,0,37.828,18.198,37.828,40.578v3.819H54.621z"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="2000" height="2000" fill="#000000" clip-path="url(#elroyclip)"/>
    </svg>
```

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PsP36/

i want to cut that clippath out of the rectangle, so i have a black rectangle with that shape as a hole. i thought by setting clip-rule="evenodd" i can achieve this, but it doesn't work. i cannot use a mask, i tried that, but in my use-case it is far too slow, whereas my tests with clipped shapes work very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to have the clipPath be the shape you're clipping in one direction and the clip area in another e.g.

```html
    <svg style="position: absolute; z-index: 100;" width="100%" height="100%" 
         viewPort="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="elroyclip">
                <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0,0H2000V2000H-2000zM54.621,44.397V60.23h15.434v7.456H47.66V44.397H27.99v23.289H5.594V60.23h15.443V44.397H0v-3.819C0,18.198,16.965,0,37.826,0c20.863,0,37.828,18.198,37.828,40.578v3.819H54.621z"/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="2000" height="2000" fill="#000000" clip-path="url(#elroyclip)"/>
    </svg>
```